# How to detect if the object $error in an AngularJs form is empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get a button disabled if any error is given in a form.

```
form(name="myForm", action="", method="post", novalidate)
.
.
.
    input(type="submit", value="Register" ng-disabled="//I need to get true here")
```

I have trying something like `ng-disabled=myform.$error` but the button is disabled even if any error is reported. What can I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid"`. This should work as $valid is true only if all fields in the form are valid